# Creating checkers pieces using a 2D array - Pygame

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pygame, geometry, iteration

I'm making a game of checkers in python by using the library `pygame`, which I am relatively new at. However I have encountered a problem with the program where too many red and black pieces are created and they are not in the correct layout.

The pieces are just circles drawn with the colour red or black. To get the layout for the pieces I have created a 2D array in the function `newGameBoard()` which places where the the pieces will go but when I iterate through that gameBoard in the function `drawPieces()` creates a block of 24 pieces on each side of the board instead of piece in the position of the game board created.

Here is the current code:

```
import pygame

newGame=True
loggedIn=False
miniGame=False

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
red=(255,0,0)
greyBackground =(203, 206, 203)

# This sets the WIDTH and HEIGHT of each grid location
width=65
height=65
radius=30

margin=0# This sets the margin between each cell

xDistanceFromEdge=220

pygame.init()

gameBoard=[[None]*8]*8

windowSize= [960, 640]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)

pygame.display.set_caption("Draughts Game")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()



# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = (pos[0]-xDistanceFromEdge) // (width+margin)
            row = pos[1] // (height+margin)


    screen.fill(greyBackground)

    def boardGui(black,white):
        for boardRow in range(8):
            for boardColumn in range(8):
                xCoordinate=((margin+width) * boardColumn + margin)+xDistanceFromEdge
                yCoordinate=(margin+height) * boardRow + margin
                if boardRow%2==0 and boardColumn%2==0:
                    currentColour = black
                if boardRow%2!=0 and boardColumn%2==0:
                    currentColour = white
                if boardRow%2==0 and boardColumn%2!=0:
                    currentColour = white
                if boardRow%2!=0 and boardColumn%2!=0:
                    currentColour = black
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,currentColour,[xCoordinate,yCoordinate, width, height])

    def piecesGameBoard(gameBoard):
        if newGame==True:
            newGameBoard(gameBoard)

    def newGameBoard(gameBoard):
        for x in range(8):
            for y in range(3):
                if ((x%2!=0) and (y%2==0)) or ((x%2==0) and (y%2!=0)):
                    gameBoard[x][y]="NormalBlack"

            for y in range(5,8):
                if ((x%2==0) and (y%2==0)) or ((x%2!=0) and (y%2!=0)):
                    gameBoard[x][y]="NormalRed"
        print(gameBoard)

        drawPieces(gameBoard,black,red)

    def drawPieces(gameBoard,black,red):
        for x in range(8):
            for y in range(8):
                xCoordinate=((margin+width) * x + margin+32)+xDistanceFromEdge
                yCoordinate=(margin+height) * y + margin+33
                if gameBoard[x][y]=="NormalBlack":
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)

                if gameBoard[x][y]=="kingBlack":
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)
                    #-----put letter k in the middle-----#
                if gameBoard[x][y]=="NormalRed":
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)

                if gameBoard[x][y]=="KingRed":
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)
                    #----put letter k in the middle---#

    boardGui(black,white)
    piecesGameBoard(gameBoard)

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I have tried to just create the pieces in the `newGameBoard()` function which did work however. With this program the `gameBoard` changes after every move which is why I would like the program to create the pieces in the format of the of the `gameBoard` variable.

Comment: Please create a **minimal** application that exhibits your problem — don't just cut and paste your whole program into your question.

Comment: I have tried to shorten down the code to where I think the problems maybe. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Now that's more like it, although you deleted one color definition too many. I've edited your question and added it, as well as attempted to improve it is several other aspects.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that I think does what you. I think the main problem was with how you were initializing the `gameboard` variable:

```
gameBoard=[[None]*8]*8
```

which I changed to:

```
gameBoard=[[None]*8 for _ in range(8)]  # Proper initialization.
```

So it would create a new column of `None` values for each row instead of putting the same list in each one. This is a common Python newbie "gotcha".

I also tried to clean-up, simplify, and organize the code structure to some degree. One notable change is I moved all those function definitions outside the main loop—as there's no reason to do that more than once and it just slows execution down.

There are still a number of other optimizations that could be done, but since you aren't asking for a full code review (which wouldn't be appropriate here anyway—there's another site called [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) for that kind of thing), I refrained from implementing any of them...

```
import pygame

newGame=True
loggedIn=False
miniGame=False

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
red=(255,0,0)
greyBackground=(203, 206, 203)

# This sets the WIDTH and HEIGHT of each grid location
width=65
height=65
radius=30

margin=0# This sets the margin between each cell
xDistanceFromEdge=220
#gameBoard=[[None]*8]*8
gameBoard=[[None]*8 for _ in range(8)]  # Proper initialization.
windowSize=[960, 640]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
pygame.display.set_caption("Draughts Game")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Added helper function.
def square_colour(row, col):
    """ Determine colour of game board square from its position. """
    return white if (row + col) % 2 == 0 else black  # Makes upper-left corner white.

def boardGui(black,white):
    for boardRow in range(8):
        for boardColumn in range(8):
            xCoordinate=((margin+width) * boardColumn + margin)+xDistanceFromEdge
            yCoordinate=(margin+height) * boardRow + margin
            currentColour = square_colour(boardRow, boardColumn)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,currentColour,[xCoordinate,yCoordinate, width, height])

def piecesGameBoard(gameBoard):
    if newGame:
        newGameBoard(gameBoard)

def newGameBoard(gameBoard):
    gameBoard[:] = [[None]*8 for _ in range(8)]  # Empty the game board.

    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            if square_colour(x, y) == black:
                if y in range(3):
                    gameBoard[x][y]="NormalBlack"
                if y in range(5,8):
                    gameBoard[x][y]="NormalRed"

    drawPieces(gameBoard,black,red)

def drawPieces(gameBoard,black,red):
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            xCoordinate=((margin+width) * x + margin+32)+xDistanceFromEdge
            yCoordinate=(margin+height) * y + margin+33
            if gameBoard[x][y]=="NormalBlack":
                pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)
                # Draw a white outline around edge of black pieces so they are visible
                # when placed on black game board squares.
                pygame.draw.circle(screen,white,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius, 1)
            if gameBoard[x][y]=="KingBlack":
                pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)
                #-----put letter k in the middle-----#
            if gameBoard[x][y]=="NormalRed":
                pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)
            if gameBoard[x][y]=="KingRed":
                pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,(xCoordinate,yCoordinate),radius)
                #----put letter k in the middle---#

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = (pos[0]-xDistanceFromEdge) // (width+margin)
            row = pos[1] // (height+margin)

    screen.fill(greyBackground)
    boardGui(black,white)
    piecesGameBoard(gameBoard)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Checkerboard displayed:

[image: screenshot of checkerboard displayed]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and this has been very helpful.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. One additional suggestion I have is to replace all those `"NormalBlack"`, `"KingBlack"`, etc hardcoded strings with the name of variables that contain the constant values associated with each one. This will avoid problems that can occur if one is ever misspelling (as is the case in code in your revised question). Furthermore, they don't need to be strings, any set of unique integer values would work just as well and comparison to their value would no longer require comparing strings, which generally is going to take longer to do that simply comparing single integer values.

Comment: Regarding the last suggestion, here's what I mean: `NormalBlack, KingBlack, NormalRed, KingRed = 0, 1, 2, 3`, then in the rest of the code always use these variable names in place of the quoted strings: e.g. `if gameBoard[x][y] == KingBlack: ...`. Actually, following the [**PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which requires the name of constants to be all uppercase, they should be `NORMAL_BLACK, KING_BLACK, NORMAL_RED, KING_RED = 0, 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: Thanks. Would i need to pass these variable into every function i'm using it for

Comment: While you could do that, for "constant" variables—literally an oxymoron—that never change, I'd make them globals. The bad things you've probably heard about using global variables, e.g [_Global Variables Are Bad_](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) or [_Global Variables Considered Harmful_](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful), don't apply to constants since their values don't change.

Comment: Re My last point about it being OK to make variables which are constant globals: If your program gets larger and split-up into more than one script (i.e. modules), you can put all of them in a file called `game_constants.py` and then `from game_constants import NORMAL_BLACK, KING_BLACK, etc...`  or even `from game_constants import *` wherever access to them is needed.

Comment: That's quite useful as well because the program was getting quite large. Thank you again very much.

Comment: Happy you found it helpful. Note also the importing the same module multiple times in the same program is relatively cheap because the results are cached and reused if it's done again. I mentioned it and the other things because I suspected you were eventually going to end up with a great deal of code—which is a lot easier to develop if it's broken up into smaller chunks of logically related functions, data, and data-structures. I also felt it was worthwhile assisting someone who seemed serious about wanting to improved their design and coding skills. Your responses have borne that out.